# How to Store rows from a MySQL table into an array in Java

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to store rows from a database table into an array. I always get this error 'class or interface , enum expected' in my NetBeans IDE 7.1.1

This is the code I've written

```
<table border="2">
   <tr>
      <th>Coop No</th>
      <th>Salutation</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Middle Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Form Type</th>
   </tr>
   <%! double[][] g_testdata;
      ResultSet rs = null;
      %>           
   <% 
      //ResultSet rs = null;

      try
      {     
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //Load the driver– Not required in Java SE 6.0 and later (JDBC 4.0 and later), the driver is loaded automatically.
           String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/cooperative";
           String uName = "root";
           String uPass = "Hecares4me";

           //Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, username, password );
           Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass );

           Statement st = con.createStatement( );
           String SQL = "SELECT transfacdept.transfacdept_id, transfacdept.faculty_id, transfacdept.department_id, transfaculties.faculty_id, transfaculties.facultyname FROM transfacdept, transfaculties WHERE transfacdept.transfacdept_id = transfaculties.faculty_id ";
           rs = st.executeQuery( SQL );
           //ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT transfacdept.transfacdept_id, transfacdept.faculty_id, transfacdept.department_id, transfaculties.faculty_id, transfaculties.facultyname FROM transfacdept, transfaculties WHERE transfacdept.transfacdept_id = transfaculties.faculty_id"); 

           g_testdata = new double[5][6]; 

           int numRows, numCols;

           if(!rs.next()){
               return;
           }
           rs.last();
           numRows = rs.getRow();
           numCols = rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
           out.println(numRows + " " + numCols);
           //rs.first();
           while(rs.next()){

                   for (int i=1; i <= numRows; i++)
                   {
                           for (int j=1; j <= numCols; j++) // populate the test data array
                           {
                                   g_testdata[i][j] = rs.getDouble(j);
                                   out.println(g_testdata[i][j]);

                           }
                   }

           }
       }
       catch(ClassNotFoundException xcp)
       {
           out.println("The SQLException exception has occurred:");
       }
       catch( SQLException err )
       {
           out.println( err.getMessage() );
       }                                                                                                                                                                                      }     
      %>
</table>
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: don't put code into your JSP.  Use a servlet of some other webservice.  Then use JSTL to print out your data

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Good point. To add some more, you can write servlet in your own application as most of us do...

Answer (score 0):

1. Netbeans 7.1 is pretty old. Consider upgrading.
2. Don't write Java code in JSP. Write it in servlet, send it to JSP via a Bean, Read from JSP using JSTL.
3. Your way of reading ResultSet is pretty weak. Try something like below.

   public List findMyRecord(int parameter)
            {
                PreparedStatement ps = null;
                ResultSet rs=null;
                Connection con = null;
                Listlist = new ArrayList();

   ```
            try
            {
                con = DBMaster.getInstance().getConnection(); //bcs I am using connection pooling. You can use `DriverManager.getConnection`.....
                String cmd="select * from table where parameter=? ORDER BY columnName DESC";
                ps=con.prepareStatement(cmd.toLowerCase());

                ps.setInt(1, parameter);

                rs=ps.executeQuery();

                if(rs.isBeforeFirst())
                {
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        YourBean pb = new YourBean ();
                        pb.setMyData(pb.getInt("columnName"));

                        list.add(pb);
                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    if(rs!=null){rs.close();}
                    if(ps!=null){ps.close();}
                    if(con!=null){con.close();}
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return list;
     }
   ```
4. In your case, you should seriously try reading your resultset like below, which might fix your issue...

> ```
> if(rs.isBeforeFirst())
>                 {
>                     while(rs.next())
>                     {//read data}
>     })
> ```

5. Use connection pooling to make sure MySQL is not going to use 1000 connections for 1000 requests. C3P0 is easy library for that..

Comment: YourBean pb = new PatientBean();

Comment: @dapson: I am sorry, it was a mistake, I fixed it. It should be `YourBean pb = new YourBean ()`

Comment: what do you mean by YourBean?

Comment: Or how can i write a bean for this particular example code?